# Constraining a <div>'s width to a sibling <div>'s width

Tags: css, css-float, html

I have some dynamically generated charts that each get placed in a container, floated left:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="chart"> ... </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="chart"> ... </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="chart"> ... </div>
</div>
```

The above, for example, produces

[image: Sample 1]

I wanted to add captions beneath each chart, so I added sibling `<div>`s, like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="chart"> ... </div>
    <div class="caption"> ... </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="chart"> ... </div>
    <div class="caption"> ... </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="chart"> ... </div>
    <div class="caption"> ... </div>
</div>
```

This didn't work because the parent's width, not having been specified, would grow with the caption text:

[image: Sample 2]

So, how can I constrain the caption `<div>` width to the chart `<div>` width?

The chart is generated by an external jQuery library, and although I could use jQuery to obtain the generated chart's width and set the caption `<div>`'s width to that value, I'd prefer a CSS-only solution. I'd also like to avoid injecting the caption `<div>` into the chart `<div>` (though, I'm not sure how that'd help anyway).

The result I'm looking for looks more like the following (example faked via forced linebreaks):

[image: Sample 3]

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: I don't think this is possible using css only, as you haven't set a width on the parent div it is always going to grow to the width of the content in it

Comment: @Pete - Hm, might there be a way to organize my `<div>`s differently to achieve the same effect? I don't have control over what's inside the chart `<div>`, but I do have control over everything else. I can even contain the chart `<div>` in another `<div>` if that helps, somehow. I lack the imagination to figure out how to make use of these actions, though.

Comment: How do you put your containers side by side? With floats? Is the containers' width variable depending upon the number of bars in the charts?

Comment: You could set a max width for the text container and center align it so it will wrap the words that way but if you have a massive chart it may look silly with all the text wrapped under it

Comment: @bbxdesign - Yes, with floats, but I'm open to another way. Yes, the containers' widths are indeed variable depending on the size of the charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by applying absolute position without any positional attributes (top, bottom, left, right)

Tested only on Chrome, FF, and IE10

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.caption {
    position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YzQcs/